# How many 5 digit numbers can be made from the digits 0,1,2,3,4 if each number is a multiple of 4

Tags: combinatorics

It seems an easy question but I when I worked it I got confused
Help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Please share what you have tried and indicate why you are stuck.

Comment: The divisibility rule of 4

Comment: Also how to place 0 is making me curious and furious at the same time

Comment: Hint: Suppose $a,b,c,d,e\in \left\{0,1,2,3,4\right\}$. Consider the number $abcde$. We need that $abcde\equiv 0\mod 4$. Now clearly $$abcde\equiv de\mod 4$$ as $100$ is divisible by $4$.

Comment: That means the last two digits of the number must be a multiple of $4$.  What are the possibilities?  Note that the cases $04$, $20$, and $40$ will have to be handled separately from the others since $0$ cannot be the leading digit.  For the other cases, decide what the final two digits will be, place $0$ in the second or third position, then arrange the remaining digits.

Comment: Is each digit to be used exactly once, or can digits be repeated.  E.g., is $44444$ to be counted, or just numbers like $10324$?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: you have to count the number of ways to put 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 in order according to the following two rules.

- 0 does not come first
- the last two digits (in order) are 04, 12, 20, 24, 32 or 40.

Comment: missing $00$ and $44$, there are $8$ per "hundred"

Comment: I assumed, as have other answers and comments, that the question is looking for numbers which have digits 0, 1, 2, 3 and 4 in some order.

Answer (score 0):

Note that a number is a multiple of $4$ if and only if its last two digits are a multiple of $4$. Therefore, the last two digits must be $04,24,12,32,20,$ or $40$. For each of these pairs, we are free to choose the first three digits from the remaining numbers, so long as the first isn't a $0$. This gives $6$ numbers for each pair not containing a $0$, and $4$ numbers for each pair containing a $0$. So there are $30$ possible numbers.

Comment: Be careful.  $3 \cdot 6 + 3 \cdot 4 = 30$.